# (node:12308) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mongoose

[image]

my `package.json` file:-

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "server":  "nodemon server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "config": "^3.3.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.10.0",
    "gravatar": "^1.8.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.19",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Azeem, please have a look here and refrase your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .Btw: cool that you got an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on the new version on mongoose packages, as you can take a look here, I posted issue about it: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9966 
I suggest downgrade to version 5.11.15. When this version is installed there is no warning.